# set the channel discord.py bot.I can't figure out how to do this function

Tags: discord.py

I want that I wrote set_channel #report and the bot saved the channel and then the bot sent reports there and when the participants wrote !report the bot sent a message to the channel that I set.
If this is possible, please give the code.I will be grateful!

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is not a website for handing out code.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking questions and not spoon feeding you the whole code, try to learn how to do it your self and when you get errors come here.

Answer (score 0):

this community has been founded to help people with their development still people show their effort and do a bit of research before landing here. but apparently it seems that you either don't have your own code or you don't want to share it. however, i am going to help you out with only the snippet required to send messages to a specific channel.

firstly, you need to enable developer mode in the discord application. for that go to user settings> appearence and enable it. now right click on a channel to which the report are supposed to be sent and copy its id.

on your .py file, make an identifier and use the get_channel() function. example:

```
client = discord.Client()
rep_channel = client.get_channel(<channel id here>)
```

now to send reports all you need to do is call the send() function through this object and not through the `message.channel` one.